# Bootstrap modal data-dismiss button is posting the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a form inside a bootsrap modal. When I click submit it posts the data and hides the modal. GREAT! However, if I click the cancel button that has data-dismiss attribute it also submits the form. I tried explicit type="button" but it still submits the form. I'd like for the "Cancel" button to just close the modal and not do postback. Any suggestions?

```
<div Class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div Class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div Class="modal-content">
            <div Class="modal-header">
                <h4 Class="modal-title">Change User</h4>
            </div>
            <div Class="modal-body">
                @If Model.impersonate.isAllowed Or Model.isAdmin Then
                @<form action='@Url.Action("Parent")' id="frmChangeUser" method="post">
                    @If Model.isAdmin Then
                        @<Label Class="lbl">Enter RACF Or EIN</Label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) Model.userRacf, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                    Else
                        @<Label Class="lbl">Select an Operator</Label>
                        @<select id="select" class="form-control" onchange="$("#userRacf").val($(this).val());">
                            @For Each item In Model.impersonate.AccessList
                                @<option value="@item.Value.ToString">@item.Text.ToString</option>
                            Next
                        </select>
                        @<input type="text" id="userRacf" name="userRacf"/>
                    End If
                    <div Class="modal-footer">
                        <Button Class="btn-green" type="submit" id="getUser">Get</button>
                        <Button Class="btn-grey" type="button" data-dismiss>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                Else
                    @<label>You are not currently registered for impersonation, to request access fill out form on homepage</label>
                    @<Button Class="btn-grey" data-dissmiss="modal">OK</button>
                End If
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal-footer button is missing "modal" should be -

```
<Button Class="btn-grey" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```